# Print a placeholder in bold within a sentence, using tags. AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tag_config'

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, tkinter

If I select City in the combobox, I would like to print London placeholder in bold. London only in bold, the rest of the sentence not in bold. I've never used tags, so I'm having a hard time, sorry for my difficulty. I would like to obtain:

**LONDON** Phrase1, Phrase2, Phrase3.

I get the error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tag_config'`

How to solve? I would like to try to maintain this code structure, or at least a similar structure.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")

combobox=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 16)
combobox.place(x=15, y=10)
combobox['value'] = ["City", "Other"]


textbox = tk.Text(root,width=20,height=4)
textbox.place(x=15, y=50)

def function1():
    if combobox.get() == "City":
        city = "London" #city = diz[sel_city]["City"]
        city_start = city.upper()
        city_start.tag_config(font=("Verdana", 14, 'bold'))


    def function2():
        text =  f"{city_start} Phrase1, Phrase2, Phrase3"
                
        textbox.delete(1.0,END)     
        textbox.insert(tk.END, text) #.format(allenat_random=allenat_random, variable_random=variable_random))

    function2()


Button = Button(root, text="Print", command=function1)
Button.pack()
Button.place(x=15, y=130)
 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to call `.tag_config()` on instance of `Text` widget, i.e. `textbox`, and you need to provide a *tag* as the first argument.  Then you need to call `textbox.tag_add(tag, index1, index2)` to apply the effect on the provided index range.

Comment: @acw1668 I don't think I understand. Can you show me how to write please? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `.tag_config()` should be called on instance of `Text` widget, i.e. `textbox` in your case.  Also the first argument of `.tag_config()` should be a tag name.

Then `.tag_add()` should be used to apply the configured effect on the text.

Below is the modified `function1()`:

```py
def function1():
    if combobox.get() == "City":
        city = "London" #city = diz[sel_city]["City"]
        city_start = city.upper()
        textbox.tag_config('city', font=("Verdana", 14, 'bold')) ### added tag argument


    def function2():
        text =  f"{city_start} Phrase1, Phrase2, Phrase3"

        textbox.delete(1.0,END)
        textbox.insert(tk.END, text) #.format(allenat_random=allenat_random, variable_random=variable_random))

        ### search city_start
        idx = textbox.search(city_start, 1.0)
        ### apply effect on city_start
        textbox.tag_add('city', idx, f'{idx}+{len(city_start)}c')

    function2()
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: What is that final C? I'm talking about C in {len (city_start)} c '). What is it for? What is its purpose? However, now it is deep night with me. Tomorrow (ie in a few hours) I try your code and accept the answer. Thank you, you've been kind

Comment: The `c` means character.